# How can I implement a custom RNN (specifically an ESN) in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I am trying to define my own RNNCell (Echo State Network) in Tensorflow, according to below definition.

x(t + 1) = tanh(Win*u(t) + W*x(t) + Wfb*y(t))

y(t) = Wout*z(t)

z(t) = [x(t), u(t)]

x is state, u is input, y is output. Win, W, and Wfb are not trainable. All weights are randomly initialized, but W is modified like this: "Set a certain percentage of elements of W to 0, scale W to keep its spectral radius below 1.0

I have this code to generate the equation.

```
x = tf.Variable(tf.reshape(tf.zeros([N]), [-1, N]), trainable=False, name="state_vector")
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N, N], 0.0, 0.05), trainable=False)
# TODO: setup W according to the ESN paper
W_x = tf.matmul(x, W)

u = tf.placeholder("float", [None, K], name="input_vector")
W_in = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([K, N], 0.0, 0.05), trainable=False)
W_in_u = tf.matmul(u, W_in)

z = tf.concat(1, [x, u])
W_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([K + N, L], 0.0, 0.05))
y = tf.matmul(z, W_out)
W_fb = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([L, N], 0.0, 0.05), trainable=False)
W_fb_y = tf.matmul(y, W_fb)

x_next = tf.tanh(W_in_u + W_x + W_fb_y)

y_ = tf.placeholder("float", [None, L], name="train_output")
```

My problem is two-fold. First I don't know how to implement this as a superclass of RNNCell. Second I don't know how to generate a W tensor according to above specification.

Any help about any of these question is greatly appreciated. Maybe I can figure out a way to prepare W, but I sure as hell don't understand how to implement my own RNN as a superclass of RNNCell.

Comment: Hi Kureta, Im interrest in using ESN but lack coding experience to build my own RNNCell. Did you finaly succeed? If yes it is possible to share your code? Thank a lot for your attention.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To give a quick summary:

Look in the TensorFlow source code under `python/ops/rnn_cell.py` too see how to **subclass** RNNCell.  It's usually like this:

```
class MyRNNCell(RNNCell):
  def __init__(...):

  @property
  def output_size(self):
  ...

  @property
  def state_size(self):
  ...

  def __call__(self, input_, state, name=None):
     ... your per-step iteration here ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I may arrive a bit late but for anybody trying to do the same, tensorflow-addons added an implementation of [ESNCell](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/ea99e7adcba6bbc42398433c47c255e57ffcacdb/tensorflow_addons/rnn/cell.py#L625) and [ESN layer](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/edc8ef0d9d849f37fa02cbc1ac67dae5c6f7668b/tensorflow_addons/layers/esn.py).

Comment: Hello, do you have any information in why the ESN from tensorflow-addons is so slow to train? I have a `Conv1D` model with `Trainable params: 670,160` that takes 1.64 minutes to train. My `ESN` got only `Trainable params: 26,124` and it takes 7.28 minutes to train. Using the same `batch_size` and `epochs`. Are `ESN` that hard to train? Theoretically speaking, i thought they were easier to train because of only the redout weights are updated after the whole batch being fed to the network. I have made this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74722946/esn-slow-to-train-model